# Trying to set up an application in IIS gives me error: Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I created a web application by going to IIS right-clicking on **Default Web Site** and selecting **Add Application**.  Then I give the Alias name, select **DefaultAppPool** and point it to Physical path.

When I try to browse to http://localhost/mywebapp  I get 'Access is denied' with following details:

> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
>   configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory
>   or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication
>   methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's
>   administrator for additional assistance.

- **Anonymous Authentication** is enabled on the IIS Website.
- The web application is ASP.NET MVC5 application.
- The web application is running under its default identity: **ApplicationPoolIdentity**

Here are the settings for DefaultAppPool

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your application is not on a network share or in the windows user (magic) directory. (It can be in the Visual Studio default magic user directory if you follow my instructions below)

If you're on Win7, create a new MVC 3 application, ^F5 to run. Then in solution explorer, right click the project and select properties. In the left pane, select the Web tab. The default is Cassini ( Use Visual Studio Development Server). Select the next radio, Use Local IIS Web server. Now ^F5 and it will launch your app from IIS.  You can also find your application in IIS manager and in the right pane, select browse 80. Now that it's working, compare the differences in your two application.

Your approach should also work. You might try creating a new MVC application and use your approach to test on IIS. The most common mistake is creating a vDir, not an application

The error message is pretty good. To set ACLS on the application pool identity, follow the instructions under **Securing Resources** at  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Also see [Understanding Built-In User and Group Accounts in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis/)

IF the new MVC app should fail, repeat, but create a Web Forms app.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `IUSR` has permission to the directory that `webapp` is sitting in.

Also, if your application is accessing permissioned resources(File IO, MSMQ...etc), you will have to change the `Identity` of the app pool or make sure ISUR has permission.

Comment: I did that. I went to my webapp folder, added IUSR and gave it full control. I get same error.

Comment: Can you elaborate on changing Identity of app pool?  My app is using DefaultAppPool. Under Advanced Settings->ProcessModel the Identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity.  I can also change it to one of the built-in accounts: LocalService, LocalSystem, NetworkService. Or set it to Custom Account. Which Identity should it be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `NETWORK SERVICE` account (or whatever system account IIS is using) has permissions to the application folder.

To check the system account that's being used, go to the application pool settings, and the system account will be listed under the `Identity` tab:

[image]

**EDIT**

Make sure that the application is using the correct application pool. Also, if you haven't already specified a default document, that could be your problem. You can test this by including a page name in the URL, e.g. `http://localhost/mywebapp/default.aspx`

Comment: How do I find out what account IIS is using?

Comment: I'm using IIS7 so it's set up to use ApplicationPoolIdentity by default http://i.imgur.com/95bMK.png   not sure what ApplicationPoolIdentity is suppose to be.

Comment: You have to apply the folder permissions too, to give `NETWORK SERVICE` the necessary access to the folder.

Comment: Gave NETWORK SERVICE read/execute rights to the folder. No change. :(

Comment: So am I. I guess will never know.